# How to set array to equal to values in 2D array, in column stored in a third array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have some 2D array `surf` like this: (But much, much longer. Tens of thousands in many cases)

```
surf = [10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30
        10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30
        10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30
        10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30]
```

I also have an array "section" like this: (same number of rows as surf)

Values can be NaN.

```
section = [4
           NaN
           6
           2]
```

That array tells me which column in `surf` I need to get, *for each row*.

I ultimately want to construct a third array which would look like this:

```
output = [20
          NaN
          30
          10]
```

Where each value is the row in the `surf` array, at the row defined by `section` for that same row.

I'm very confused about how to go about this.
I tried something like:

```
myArray = surf(:, section);
```

but for obvious reasons that doesn't work. section is an array of values, not a single value.

I'm very new to MATLAB and only have experience with very different languages, and would appreciate any help. I'm new to all the vectorized/implicit looping/etc stuff that MATLAB seems to do.

Comment: do you simply need `output = surf(1,section)` ? Also explain why it doesn't work. And this sentence `Where each value is the row in the surf array, at the row defined by section for that same row.` is totally unclear.

Comment: Like I said, I know what the output should look like, not what the command should be. I'm new to MATLAB's practices. In any case, either trying ```surf(1, section)``` or ```surf(:, section)``` fail because "Subscript indices must be either real positive integers or logicals". It's because "section" is an array and not an index, as far as I can tell.

Comment: According to your example it should not fail. Matlab support linear AND logical indexing. So please provide an example that reproduce your problem.

Comment: @obchardon How odd. The simple example in the OP does seem to work. I know this seems like a large oversight, but it might be because the section can be NaN. This was a non-problem for doing similar array operations, so I didn't think it mattered here either. Hmm.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question itself. The way of saying thanks on SO is accepting an answer (thanks for doing that). If you want to add your own solution: great! Please add an answer yourself. This is not forbidden, on the contrary, it's even encouraged!

Comment: @Adriaan I sometimes like to give specifics if my implementation of the solution was slightly different from the actual one I marked as correct for the sake of solving the problem. In this case, I mis-read and the exact solution ended up being in the answer I marked, but in other cases sometimes they are not.

Comment: That's no problem, sorry if it came across that way. It's the system of Stack Overflow that the question-part contains just a question, and *any* answers, including your own, go in separate answers. It's not for naught that it is that easy to self-answer your question: you're encouraged to share knowledge. Please do so in the future! This also helps you, since you can get upvotes on both question and answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three attempts. Note that I have changed your variable name to `mysurf` since `surf` is a MATLAB function, and I have changed the data to make it clearer which one has been selected:

```
mysurf = [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6
           7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12
          13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18
          19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24];

section = [4
           NaN
           6
           2];


% first attempt by replacing NaN...       
tmp = section;

tmp(isnan(tmp)) = 1;

result1 = NaN(size(section));
for c = 1 : numel(result1)
    result1(c) = mysurf(c, tmp(c));
end
% and changing the result to NaN afterwards
result1(isnan(section)) = NaN;

% Second attempt by using an if

result2 = NaN(size(section));
for c = 1 : numel(result2)
    if ~isnan(section(c))
        result2(c) = mysurf(c, section(c));
    end
end
```

**Update** And as a bonus, here is one attempt without using a loop (as challenged by  @obchardon's answer):

```
mysurf = [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6
           7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12
          13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18
          19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24];

section = [4
           NaN
           6
           2];

width = size(mysurf,2);

tmp = mysurf';

linidx = ((1:numel(section))-1) .* width + section';

result = NaN(size(section));

result(~isnan(linidx)) = tmp(linidx(~isnan(linidx)));
```

Comment: I ended up just using that bottom loop, as it was the easiest to explain and doesn't feel "hacky" to explain/show a coworker. It may not be the most efficient, but I was stubborn and should have just done it from the start. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In this case a for loop is probably more suited, but if your want a vectorized solution:

```
% Define matrix size
m    = 5;
n    = 6;
% Random matrix
A    = round(rand(m,n)*10)
% Index including NaN value
idx1 = [1 NaN 3 4 5];
% Correction of the row index to get a linear index, it will also delete the NaN value
% Sub2ind could have done the same job, but sub2ind does not support NaN value 
% so we save a few line here
idx2 = fillmissing(idx1,'c',1)*m-m+[1:m];
% Get the value and retrieve the NaN value
out  = A(idx2).*idx1./idx1
```

For

```
A =

   4   8   9   1   8   9
   2   8   0   2   7   2
   4   4   2   9   7   3
   9   0   8   7   0   9
   0   1   9   6   7   8
```

Out will be:

```
out =

     4   NaN     2     7     7
```

Answer (score 0):

As @obchardon commented, the typical way of doing this, is:

```
result = surfs(1, section)
```

Output:

> result = 20   20   30   10

---

But since you say that this doesn't work, you could use a for loop, like this:

```
surfs = [10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30; 10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30; 10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30; 10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30]
section = [4; 4; 6; 2]

result = zeros(length(section), 1)
for i = 1 : length(result)
    result(i) = surfs(i, section(i))
end
```

Output:

> result = 20   20   30   10